# Why are database entries being automatically created when I visit the "new" page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble understanding why my app is automatically creating entries in the database when I visit the "new" page. The page is supposed to have a form that, when submitted, then and *only* then creates entries in the database (SQLite3).

Controller:

```
    class RecipeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.all
  end

  def new

    @recipe = Recipe.create(params[:recipe])
    if @recipe.save
        redirect_to recipe_new_path
    else
        reload_page
    end
  end

  def create

    @recipe = Recipe.new

  end

  def show
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

  def recipe_params

    recipe_params = params.require(:recipes)
  end


end
```

The view:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Add a recipe</h1>
    <%= form_for @recipe do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name, "Recipe Name:" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :recipe, "Recipe Description:" %>
    <%= f.text_field :recipe %>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
</body>
</html>
```

Routes file:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'recipe' => 'recipe#index'
  get 'recipe/new' => 'recipe#new'
  post 'recipe/create' => 'recipe#create'
  post 'recipes' => 'recipe#create'
  resources :recipes
  get 'recipe/:id' => 'recipe#show'
  get 'recipe/update' => 'recipe#update'
  get 'recipe/destroy' => 'recipe#destroy'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the controller, the logic to create a Recipe has been written  in new method and just a recipe is just initialized in create method.
But in the routes the create method has a POST call(form submission with data) and the new method is a GET.

So all you need to do is just change the name of the 'create' method as 'new'
and change the name of the 'new' method as 'create' in your controller.

i.e)

```
def create
    @recipe = Recipe.create(params[:recipe])
    if @recipe.save
        redirect_to recipe_new_path
    else
        reload_page
    end
  end

  def new
   @recipe = Recipe.new
  end
```

This will work.