# Rails app only adding "created_at" and "updated_at" to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

(using sqlit3)

I've just succeeded in making form submission work- however, all the fields aren't submitted. Only Rails' default "updated_at" and "created_at" values are.

Code is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53685011/why-are-database-entries-being-automatically-created-when-i-visit-the-new-page) post.

Comment: Please do add these details in your question
1. Rails version
2. Can you also post the POST request params?
3. re you getting any error? If so what are the errors?

Comment: 1) 5.2.2, 2) I removed the params, as they were causing issues/errors. 3) No, no errors. It's very strange.

Comment: Can you post the error trace?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `permit` the attributes that can be used by the controller for updation/creation.
In your case you need to permit the fields `name` and `recipe`.

*In your controller methods,change recipe_params like this*:

```
def recipe_params
    recipe_params = params.require(:recipe).permit(:name,:recipe)
  end
```

and in *your `create` method, call the method `recipe_params` instead of directly using `params[:recipe]` to create*.
i.e:

```
 def create
    @recipe = Recipe.create(recipe_params)
    if @recipe.save
        redirect_to recipe_new_path
    else
        reload_page
    end
 end
```

This should work.

Comment: When I do this, I get an error saying "param is missing or the value is empty".

Comment: Can you post the full trace including the error message?
Also can you check if your recipe_params code is 'params.require(:recipe).permit(:name,:recipe)?

Comment: That's the full trace

Comment: there is no error message in that link?
Where are you getting this error,"param is missing or the value is empty"??

Comment: alright I got the original issue fixed... now the only problem is that Rails is displaying unwanted params (I think) in the "view" section...

Comment: Your issue isn't clear?! Perhaps post screenshot of the view you are getting or share the entire log trace.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the Recipe Controller

```
def recipe_params
 recipe_params = params.require(:recipe).permit(:name,:recipe)
end
```

this method allows you select parameters to be added

create action as usual

```
def create
 @recipe = Recipe.create(recipe_params)
 if @recipe.save
    redirect_to recipe_new_path
 else
    reload_page
 end
end
```

then your form should look like this,pay attention to the `:recipe` symbol

```
<%= form_for :recipe do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name, "Recipe Name:" %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<br>
<%= f.label :recipe, "Recipe Description:" %>
<%= f.text_field :recipe %>
<br>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Note in your form,you had this @recipe instead of `:recipe`,hence that resulted in the missing param error message,just make sure you have the same variable in the controller and form.