# Rails displaying unwanted text from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails is displaying unwanted things from the database (sqlite3), like this:

```
Recipes
Cookies

Text here

Cake

Text here
[#<Recipe id: 50, name: "Cookies", Recipe: "Text here", created_at: "2018-12-09 05:36:46", updated_at: "2018-12-09 05:36:46">, #<Recipe id: 51, name: "Cake", scam: "Text here", created_at: "2018-12-09 18:54:11", updated_at: "2018-12-09 18:54:11">]
```

Controller is in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53685011/why-are-database-entries-being-automatically-created-when-i-visit-the-new-page).

view code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Recipe Masterlist</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>Recipes</h1>
   <%= @recipes.each do |s| %>
    <span class="name"><%= s.name %></span>
    <p><%= s.recipe %></p>
   <% end %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the view's code?

Comment: No problem, let me make a paste

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zmKhcXs8

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
<%= @recipes.each do |s| %>
```

To this

```
<% @recipes.each do |s| %>
```

The `=` displays what is inside the code.  I suspect that is your culprit